# How to clear a POSIX Message Queue?

Tags: c++, posix, message-queue

I am currently working on a program that does IPC via Posix Message Queues. I now need a function that removes every message of that queue. The problem is: My code deadlocks. Currently I am trying the following:

```
void clear_mq(std::string queue_name)
{
    struct mq_attr mq_attrs = {0, 10, sizeof(uint8_t), 0};

    mqd_t mq = ::mq_open(queue_name.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 00644, &mq_attrs);

    if (mq < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening Queue" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct mq_attr num_messages;
    if (mq_getattr(mq, &num_messages) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    while (num_messages.mq_curmsgs > 0)
    {
        uint8_t buf;
        mq_receive(mq, (char *)&buf, sizeof(uint8_t), NULL);
        if (mq_getattr(mq, &num_messages) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    mq_close(mq);
}
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? I do not understand why the receive is blocking... At that moment when I call `clear_mq` noone else is in the receive block...

Answer (score 1):

Could be that `mq_receive()` fails and you end up in a endless loop.

`mq_receive()` can fail for various reasons, e.g. the buffer provided must at least have the size of the `mq-maxsize`.

You should check the return value of mq_receive() and exit the loop if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You IMHO have no deadlock. However, the `mq_receive` blocks until it receives a message ([man mq_receive](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_receive)) because the queue is not open with O_NONBLOCK parameter while `mq_open`.

Please also ensure you do not neglect the return value of the `mq_receive` in the loop.

Comment: Yes, but I am making sure it only goes into the `mq_receive` call when messages are available (via `mq_getattr`). The result tho is a good point, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has the problem.

When printing the [errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) I get error 9 (Bad file descriptor), which makes sense cause the message queue is only opened for write but you are trying to read from it. When you open the queue with `O_RDWR` see [mq_open](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_open) it should work.

A tip for debugging use `mq_timedreceive` so that you can check the error.